# I am trying to create a regular expression that would search for letters that repeat in a string

Tags: javascript

E.g. "asdoekrikkm", i want a regex that will match the "k" because it repeats in the string.
I am trying to use string.match(regex) to do that, but i am not sure how to structure the regex.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a capture group and a back reference:

```js
const match = "asdoekrikkm".match(/(.)\1/)[1];
console.log(match);
```

`(.)` finds any character and stores it in a capture group. `\1` is a back reference to the first character. `(.)\1` searches for two same consecutive characters. `.match` returns an array with the full match (both consecutive characters) and the the capture group. `"asdoekrikkm".match(/(.)\1/)[0]` is the full match (two characters) and `"asdoekrikkm".match(/(.)\1/)[1]` is the capture group (one character).